# how to sort a pandas dataframe according to elements of list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a the following dataframe:

```
          x-coord       y-coord
1         1150.0        1760.0
2          630.0        1660.0
3           40.0        2090.0
4          750.0        1100.0
5          750.0        2030.0
6         1030.0        2070.0
7         1650.0         650.0
8         1490.0        1630.0
9          790.0        2260.0
10         710.0        1310.0
11         840.0         550.0
12        1170.0        2300.0
13         970.0        1340.0
14         510.0         700.0
15         750.0         900.0
16        1280.0        1200.0
17         230.0         590.0
18         460.0         860.0
19        1040.0         950.0
20         590.0        1390.0
21         830.0        1770.0
22         490.0         500.0
23        1840.0        1240.0
24        1260.0        1500.0
25        1280.0         790.0
26         490.0        2130.0
27        1460.0        1420.0
28        1260.0        1910.0
29         360.0        1980.0
```

and the following list:

```
['1', '28', '6', '12', '9', '5', '26', '29', '3', '2', '20', '10', '4', '15', '18', '17', '14', '22', '11', '19', '25', '7', '23', '27', '8', '24', '16', '13', '21']
```

The list contains the index of the dataframe. I am trying to rearrange the indexes of the dataframe according to the list.

```
ie, something like this
1         1150.0        1760.0
28        1260.0        1910.0
6         1030.0        2070.0
22         490.0         500.0
.............................
.............................
```

I am not having any idea of how to do this. Any idea experts?

Thanks,
Arnab

Comment: Use `df = df.reindex(L)`

Comment: But am seeing the column values turning to NaN if I do df=df.reindex(L)

Comment: Then use `df = df.reindex(np.array(L).astype(int))` - convert values to integers.

Comment: sweet, many thanks